# Why isn't my flexbox CSS working as intended?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

Why is `display:flex` not working in my CSS code? I want to make this part of my HTML code be in center of my page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex auto 0 1;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form"></form>
<h4 class="score" id="score">score :0</h4>
<h1 id="Question">What is 1 multiply by 1?</h1>
<input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Enter your answer" autofocus autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

`flex auto 0 1` is an invalid property value for `display`. Your browser's document inspector will show you this. You need to separate those values across the `display` and `flex` properties.

I suspect that you also want `flex-direction: column`, but I'll leave that to you.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto 0 1;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form"></form>
<h4 class="score" id="score">score :0</h4>
<h1 id="Question">What is 1 multiply by 1?</h1>
<input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Enter your answer" autofocus autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

the key is to wrap it in a container and make it inline block then using flex to center it :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex ;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 100vh;

}
.container{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form" id="form"></form>
   <h4 class="score" id="score">score :0</h4>
  <h1 id="Question">What is 1 multiply by 1?</h1>
  <input type="text" class="input" id="input" 
   placeholder="Enter your answer" autofocus        autocomplete="off">
   <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
</div>
```